# rsync with node.js in intel galileo linux

Tags: node.js, rsync, intel-galileo

I've been really struggling for a few days trying to get a node.js script to work on the linux distribution offered on the intel Galileo board. I am using the full size distro provided for use on the SD card, and I have used:

```
'npm install rsync'
```

to install the node.js rsync. I am trying simply to test the functionality based on the example given at the npm site. Here is what I am using:

```
-#!/usr/bin/node

var Rsync = require('rsync');

// Build the command

var rsync = new Rsync()

  .flags('az')

  .source('/home/root/documents')

  .destination('/home/root/documents_backup');


// Execute the command
rsync.execute(function(error, code, cmd) {
    // we're done
});

cmd = new Rsync()

     .flags

     .source
```

I go to the terminal, open the directory it is saved in, and type node test.js. The line "All done executing" is shown, but there are no files from "documents" in "documents_backup."

Does anyone know why this script is not working correctly?

Or how to correctly use the node.js version of rsync.

I can't seem to have any luck getting a linux distro with gcc to compile and install rsync on the galileo board, so I am afraid this may be as close as I can get to it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No experience in galileo, but do you have rsync installed itself? (does typing `rsync` into shell gives you a usage description?)

Comment: No, unfortunately the version of linux on the board does not have rsync on it already, nor can I build it because there is no gcc either. I was told that I could use 'npm install rsync' as an alternative, but do I actually need rsync installed in order to use the functionality provided by the node.js rsync? I'm afraid I don't know enough about node to understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for clearing things up in your comment.

The issue, is that `rsync` is rather a huge project, and there is little reason to implement `rsync` from the ground in Node.js, granted it is easily accessible and is available on almost all platforms.

It is not a surprise, that `rsync` module for Node.js is just a wrapper. Taken from [NPM rsync](https://www.npmjs.org/package/rsync):

> Rsync is a class for building and executing rsync commands with Node.js.

As Galileo does not have `rsync` installed by default, the module is of no use.

---

Alternatively, there seem to be few articles on how to install Debian and other full-featured linux distributions, though it seems to be rather a challenge.

Finally, rsync is double-sided program, you can instead configure `rsync` on the other end, and 
tell it to use SSH instead of rsync protocol for communicating with your Galileo server.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. Unfortunately I've so far had no luck getting a debian image to run on the board. I was trying to use rsync to sync local directories, rather than one of them being remote. The project is supposed to use the galileo board as a standalone file sync device, to sync two USB drives together with the press of a button. Are there any decent shell or node scripts that could perform a basic file sync? I haven't had much luck looking for them, but maybe someone knows of something.